# For what real number $r$ is the set $\left.\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\right| a+b+c+d=r\right\}$ a subspace of $M_2$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

$M_2$ is the vector space of all $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries. For what real number r is the set  $$\left.\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\right|a+b+c+d=r\right\}$$ a subspace of $M_2$?

Comment: What is one vector that every subspace must contain?

Comment: You mean 0 vector?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to do the question now.

Comment: Peng, now that you can answer the question, you should post an answer. Later, you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A quick solution:

   Every subspace must contain zero vector, which means  $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}|0+0+0+0=r\right\}$ is in the subspace of $M_{2}$. Hence, $r$=0.
2. Alternative solution:

   We can use the definition of subspace to find  $r$ : closed under addition and scalar multiplication.